# Why sql has 'near somewhere' as an error message?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, rdbms

There were many times that i got frustrated trying to debug a query that just told me 'near that mess of yours there is a mistake'. Why can't it tell me the mistake exactly?

Example:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'systemquery1 as ( (select data from (SELECT u.id as userid, ' at line 12

Comment: I think it’s not a question but a frustration comment

Comment: There is so many things that could go wrong in a query, from syntax, to data, to just plain wrong SQL. The db dev team can't handle every possible mistake, hence error messages like this that help point in the right direction.

Comment: @NickSuwyn I don't think it's a matter of "can" or "can't". The database engine compiles the query and knows exactly what's wrong in many cases. If you put your query in a tool or copy it to a stored procedure, you get much clearer error messages. In fact some database engines give much clearer error messages that others even for queries.

Comment: Jaime It's in part a little bit of frustration, but I still just wanted to know why it don't show the exact error as Racil pointed out.

Comment: You get what you pay for.

Comment: 99% of the time, the first token in the 'near' clause (or the token immediately before it) is the offending one.  That's better than error reporting in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

SQL parsers -- as with the parsers of many languages -- are not that smart.  They know what the language looks like.  However, they have no imagination.  When something doesn't go right they merely know that it isn't right.

Human languages don't generally have this problem.  They have a lot of redundancy built in, which helps speakers fill in missing sounds, missing words, make sense of homophones and unrecognized grammar.

Some newer database engines have gotten smarter.  For instance, I'm still impressed when BigQuery suggests the (invariably correct) variable name when I misspell something.

Comment: I don't know what languages you're referring to, but most good parsers and compilers are pretty damn smart and pin point the exact issue in the code. In fact even with SQL, if you copy the same query to inside a stored procedure, you may get clearer messages. Some databases give clearer messages than others for the same type of errors. I do agree with your answer to some extent, but the parser/compiler can tell the exact cause for many errors that are currently generic messages. To a far extent, the parser/compiler is as dumb or smart as the dev team want them to be.

Comment: @RacilHilan . . . The parser usually tells you what token is incorrect.  It doesn't provide as much guidance on what should have been there (and often the error that is found is several tokens after the actual error).

Comment: Yes, that's the exact case the OP is complaining about, but that's not the case with other good parsers including other database engines. For example, if you validate your HTML page at w3.org, you get the exact location, cause, and suggested change. And it is super accurate most of the time. The same goes with other good parsers for XML, and programming languages like JavaScript and C#. So the issue I raised with your answer is about saying that parsers are not smart, while in fact most parsers are much better than the particularly useless one in MySQL. It's a low quality issue.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons for the frustrating syntax error messages is that the MySQL and MariaDB parsers were created with the [GNU Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) parser generator. Due to the generic nature of this library, and also the way the SQL parser was implemented, you see where the error is found but not what would be expected or what would be correct.

Something that was mentioned in multiple comments is the fact that you can place the query into a stored procedure and you'll get better error messages.

Comment: I don't know if the facts in this answer are true, but it makes sense. It is clearly a parser quality issue in MySQL and MariaDB.